# MPI. Running mpi in function

Tags: function, mpi

I want to run some function using mpi from `main` but I don't know how it should be. It looks like:

```
#define MAXSIZE 100
int main (int argc, char **argv) {
  int i;
  float matrixA[MAXSIZE][MAXSIZE], matrixB[MAXSIZE][MAXSIZE], matrixC[MAXSIZE][MAXSIZE];
  for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    multiply(matrixA, matrixB, matrixC);
  }
}
void multiply(float matrixA[MAXSIZE][MAXSIZE], float matrixB[MAXSIZE][MAXSIZE], float matrixC[MAXSIZE][MAXSIZE]) {
  int rank; //process rank
  int size; //number of processes
  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv); //initialize MPI operations
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank); //get the rank
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size); //get number of processes

  ...someoperation...
  MPI_Finalize();
}
```

I know how to run basic **MPI** without using other functions but I need this construction.

Comment: MPI is distributed memory system, so data is usually not available to all the processor, So you decide what your logic should be. Usually algorithms for the parallel programming are written differently for different system ( OpenMP, mpi and cuda ) . So getting speed up using naive algorithm is almost impossible especially in mpi and cuda cases.

Comment: For this you have to scatter your matrices to other processors, and decide the policy ( which part of final array would be computed by which processor ), then gather those computed data on one processor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In an application instance, MPI can be initialized ***at most once***. So the code structure you provided will not work.

the correct structure for your program is as follows:

```
#define MAXSIZE 100
int main (int argc, char **argv) {
  int i;
  float matrixA[MAXSIZE][MAXSIZE], matrixB[MAXSIZE][MAXSIZE], matrixC[MAXSIZE][MAXSIZE];
  int rank; //process rank
  int size; //number of processes
  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv); //initialize MPI operations
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank); //get the rank
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size); //get number of processes
  for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    multiply(matrixA, matrixB, matrixC);
  }
  MPI_Finalize();
}
void multiply(float matrixA[MAXSIZE][MAXSIZE], float matrixB[MAXSIZE][MAXSIZE], float matrixC[MAXSIZE][MAXSIZE]) {    
  ...someoperation...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful to you.In your program, there is a for loop 
`for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    multiply(matrixA, matrixB, matrixC);
  }`
I feel that you are trying to execute multiplication 10 times.You can give each multiplication to one process.So you can use the command, mpirun -np 10 executable.